# Weird problems after recovery from security breach

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, errors, security

The shared server that I used for hosting my WordPress website was hacked recently, and many of the `index.php` files, plugin files and uploads were deleted, with my MySQL databases untouched. But after having restored all of it from my local backups, I'm having some weird problems.

1. My homepage http://inversekarma.in does not fully load - the sidebar and footer are missing. If I view the page source, it ends at the point where the code for my sidebar starts.
2. I am not able to login to the dashboard. It throws a 500 error.

Please help me fix this issue!

P.S.: I have another WordPress blog on the same domain, at `http://inversekarma.in/photos`, which is working perfectly without any of the above issues, after I restored the files from my backup.

Comment: After deleting all the files and then copying a fresh copy of WordPress, I also copied all of my plugins. When activating a few, the admin console breaks - no error message is printed, but just dashboard and plugins pages blank out, with only the top bar and the left toolbar visible. HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you just overwrote site from backup? Not a good way since it may easily leave broken files or even backdoors.

It is best to erase site completely, then copy clean WordPress archive and copy of your files from backup there. If possible it's best to restore database from pre-hack backup as well.

If these are not possible I suggest you find someone who handles such cases professionally. There is now way to comprehensively advice on hacking case "in theory".

Comment: Seems like instead of replacing all the files, it is better to delete them all and just copy all the files over. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Will be running the SQL queries once I get back home to check for malicious code!